# How can servlet create a file that user can visit directly

Tags: eclipse, servlets, realpath

I'm using eclipse and tomcat to develop.
It seems that only files in the `WebContent` folder can be visited by user.
And now I need to create a file dynamically in servlet,But how can I get the real path of `WebContent` folder?
I tried `getServletContext().getRealPath("")`,But it returns a path of workspace of eclipse,not the path of my project,it's something like this `D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\`,
while I would like something like this `D:\git\Monitor\WebContent`
Anybody knows the solution?~ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with my teacher's help,in another way though.
Since I can't get the real path of `WebContent`,I can modify the `server.xml` to make a local path readable for the front-end.This config file is in the `Servers` folder.
The bottom of`server.xml` is like this.

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
  <Context docBase="Monitor" path="/Monitor" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Monitor"/>
</Host>
```

And I added a `Context` node,then it's like this

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
  <Context docBase="Monitor" path="/Monitor" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Monitor"/>
  <Context docBase="D:\environment\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21-dev\user\logs" path="/Monitor/logs" reloadable="true" debug="" crossContext="true"></Context>
</Host>
```

This way,I can write files to `D:\environment\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21-dev\user\logs` in the servlet,and get the file using url `localhost:8080/Monitor/logs/fileName` in the front-end~

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Web applications (WAR files) could be deployed un-extracted, that is as a compressed archive file.

General workaround is to write a servlet, that is let the end-user download the generated file. This way you could place your files almost anywhere on your server FS...

Comment: But html files in the `Webcontent` folder can be visited by url like `http://localhost:8080/Monitor/html/index.html`.

Comment: So I thought the key problem is to get the realPath of `WebContent` so that the servlet can write file to it.

Comment: Eclipse's `WebContent` becomes the root of your WAR archive. You cannot write to there... Set up a configuration property, that holds a safe and writable path for storing your files. This depends on your server's environment....